# SQL query throw error in Visual Studio15 (Data Base Project) on a Varchar field when storing Javascript data in column through Insert query

Tags: sql, sql-server, visual-studio

I am trying to store Javascript code in a Varchar Field in SQL Server, I perform this by using Post Deployment Script. The data I try to store in Varchar field is as below:

`N'btniconclassnames:glyphicon-circelplus;btniconfontclassname:font17;isreadonly:false;elementid:1121;enc_elementpagerelid:0;linkbtnonclick:addNewPanel(''keratometryPanel'',this)||eE_ConvertMMToDiopter($(currentActivatedForm).find("div[name=K\\''s\\.UNIT]"),''HZ_POWER_OD,HZ_POWER_OS,VT_POWER_OD,VT_POWER_OS'',''1'');btnicontitle:Add'`

I have a Data Base project in Visual Studio which creates the DB for me when I publish the project. When I publish, it creates DB and insert data too into the DB. including the data that I have mentioned above. 
When I try to build the Project in Visual Studio for publish, it throws error as follows:

> Variable currentActivatedForm is not defined.

error at the data mentioned above.

Is there is a way I can over come this issue in VS and successfully build the project without any error ?

Thank You in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've run into a problem of the syntax of these scripts: `$(v)` is the syntax for replacing SQLCMD variables, even within string literals. You are not interested in using these, however, it just happens to occur in a piece of JavaScript (which is no doubt using JQuery, which also uses this syntax, but for a completely different purpose). Unfortunately, you can't turn off this mechanism.

Easiest solution: split up the string at that point so it's no longer recognized as a variable (`eE_ConvertMMToDiopter($' + N'(currentActivatedForm...'`). Slightly more involved but more generally applicable solution (because expressions are not allowed everywhere): define a variable in the project that substitutes for the dollar sign (e.g. `dollar`) and do a search-replace replacing `$` with `$(dollar)`.